# Error while trying to install website builder app on odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I was able to install that website builder app before, but it was long ago. And when I try to install it again, it gives me this error

```
ParseError: "insert or update on table "website" violates foreign key constraint "website_user_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(3) is not present in table "res_users"
```

Please let me know if I need to post the full error log. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error many times, the only way I was able to bypass the error was to delete the record causing the error.

The error message is pretty straight forward, there is a record in website module with user_id=3, while there is no user in res_users with the id 3. try to look up the record with user_id=3 in website and delete it.